# $.ajax not working and bypassing in onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My onclick event doesn't call ajax request, However function gives me both first and second alert.
here is my code.

```
 function interaction()
    {
        alert('first');

        $.ajax({
                    url: "store_setting_ajax.php",
                    dataType:'json',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:{
                        interaction1:'yes'
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        window.location.reload();

                    }
                });
       alert('second');
    }
```

I try e.preventDefault() but not working.

Comment: check console..is there any error in console??

Comment: No, it doesn't display any error

Comment: Add an error handler... See if it gets called.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a form, then put it into it's onsubmit like this:
`<form method='POST' action='' onsubmit='return interaction()'>`
And at the functions end, do a `return false;`

`type:'POST'` is kinda deprecated, use `method:'POST'` instead.
Instead of `success`use done like this:

```
$.ajax({....... your stuff .......}).done(function(data){
window.location.reload(); //whats the point of using ajax here, if you do a reload then?
})
```